# How to exit properly a never ending live matplotlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, serial-port, pyserial

I created a basic 3D animation, showing an object in 3D space, the coordinates are coming from an Arduino.

```
import serial
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

def make_the_plot(port1, baud1, duration):

    plt.ion()
    mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    port = port1 
    baudrate = baud1
    ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)

    realtime=0
    while ser and realtime<duration:

        raw = (ser.readline())
        splitted= raw.split()
        realtime=realtime+1
        #print (realtime, maxtime)
        if 'reading' in splitted:

            print("error in sensor reading")
            msg = "Error in sensor readng "+raw
            return msg  
        try:
            ax.cla()
            x=float(splitted[0])
            y=float(splitted[1])
            z=float(splitted[2])

            ax.scatter(x,y,z)
            ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
            ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
            ax.set_zlim([0, 100])
            #fig.suptitle("Title centered above all subplots", fontsize=14)
            ax.set_xlabel('x [cm]')
            ax.set_ylabel('y [cm]')
            ax.set_zlabel('z [cm]')
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.003)

        except:
            pass

        msg="time's up"

    print (msg)
    return msg    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    make_the_plot('COM7',9600,100)
```

The program works, but I can't close the plot without having issues. Most often after trying to close it the whole plot becomes white, the title changes to "Figure (Not Responding)", and after some seconds a new window with Python not responding message appears. if I call the `make_the_plot()` function from an other module (from a GUI) it's even worse. How can I modify the code to make closing procure working properly?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using threads.